# Using Enter key to move between fields inside fieldset element

Tags: javascript, html

Without `fieldset`, enter (return key) works.

What should I do if I need `fielset` inside the form? Enter is not working if I add `fieldset`

```
<HTML>
<Head>
<Script Language=JavaScript>

function toEOT(isField){

isRange = isField.createTextRange();
isRange.move('textedit');
isRange.select();
}

function actTab(isField){

if (event.keyCode == 13)
{
nextField = isField.tabIndex;
nextField++;
if (nextField < document.forms.Form1.length)
{document.forms.Form1[nextField].focus()}
else {document.forms.Form1[0].focus()}
}
}

function init(){

document.forms.Form1[0].focus();
}

window.onload=init;

</Script>
</Head>
<Body>
<Form name='Form1'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Fills</legend>
<input type=text value="This is Some Text" size=25 onfocus="toEOT(this)" onkeyup="actTab(this)" tabindex='0'><br>
<input type=text value="Some Text" size=25 onfocus="toEOT(this)" onkeyup="actTab(this)" tabindex='1'><br>
<input type=text value="Nothing" size=25 onfocus="toEOT(this)" onkeyup="actTab(this)" tabindex='2'><br>
<input type=text value="Two Words" size=25 onfocus="toEOT(this)" onkeyup="actTab(this)" tabindex='3'><br>
</fieldset>
</Form>
</Body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue, please mark it as the correct answer. If not, please comment so I can try to further assist :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing your `tabindex` parameter by 1 so that it starts from 1 instead of 0.

`tabindex` is meant to be used with positive integers, unless you're trying to achieve something a little different from what `tabindex` is usually designed to do. Read more on it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a index on each input element as id or class, then in your actTab function, you can read the index value from id or class, then you can use jquery to select the next input.